# How to set max count for repeat to getOrElse function in Option android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I've problem with max repeat count for request that returns error. In my case I need to send a new request to backend, if previous was falling, but 3 time max. I'm using option to get result, that returns data or error:

```
fun sendRequest(): Single<Option<BeResponse>
```

Inside of `sendRequest()` function I transform it from `Either<ApiError, Data>` to `BeResponse`

```
data class BeReponse(
   val error: ApiError? = null,
   val data: Data? = null
)
```

When I'm trying to get data I need to send request if previous one failed. So I'm using:

```
sendRequest().flatMap{ option -> 
    option.map {
        if (option.error != null) {
            Single.just(null.toOption())
         } else {
            Single.just(it)
         }
    }.getOrElse{ sendRequest() }
}
```

But in case when I have error I will call sendRequest endless. How I can set max attempts count for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create temp var, then increase it when the program do looping..

See this

```
var temp = 0
sendRequest().flatMap{ option -> 
    option.map {
        if (option.error != null) {
            Single.just(null.toOption())
         } else {
            Single.just(it)
         }
    }.getOrElse{
        if (temp < 3){
          sendRequest()
          temp = temp+1
       } else{
          //do your code to take action
       }
}
```